# Proper way to make variable accessible within entire .m file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

As you can tell, I'm new to Objective-C. I currently have a Singleton working, but I'm trying to use it throughout several methods within the same .m file.

Right now I use this to declare/instantiate the Singleton within a method:

```
GlobalData *globDat=[GlobalData getInstance];
```

Do I need to declare it within each method, or is there a way to do this at the top of the .m (or .h?) file so I can access it throughout the other methods?

Thanks...

(BTW I've tried placing the line of code shown above under my "@implementation" line, but I get an error: "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" which I now know is because the line is not within a method.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class extension, and store the global data in ivar, like this:

```
@interface MyClass() {
    GlobalData *globDat;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        globDat=[GlobalData getInstance];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

This will hide the `globDat` from the interface, and make it available throughout the methods you implement inside your implementation block of `MyClass`.

Comment: You've posted code that partially goes into the .h and then the .m file, correct? @interface...@end in .h, the rest in .m?

Comment: Or you can simply declare it in your .h file and make it private

Comment: @wayneh No, absolutely not: it's a class extension, it goes into the .m file. That's why the name is not simply `MyClass`, but `MyClass()` with a pair of parentheses. This is a common way of adding private ivars to the class, without the need to drag `"Global.h"` into `"MyClass.h"` .

Comment: @aqs That would require including `"Global.h"` in `"MyClass.h"`, which may not be desirable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've all the code to my .m file but am getting an error: "cannot find interface declaration for MyClass" - what did I miss?

Comment: @wayneh You need to use the name of your class in place of `MyClass`, and add `globDat=[GlobalData getInstance];` to the designated init method of your class.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I do prefer using extensions as it helps keep my .h file clean. But I thought for a beginner it would be easier to declare it in the .h file. Now as to including "Global.h" , wouldn't using the \@class Global, help?

Comment: @aqs You are definitely right about the `@class Global`, and you are probably right about declaring in the .h file being easier, too. On the other hand, if OP learns about class extensions through implementing this answer in his code, he would get a lot more value from this exercise.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm back - with a different error - I've entered the code you posted above, and now I get a new error at this line: `globDat=[GlobalData getInstance];` error: No known class method for selector 'getInstance'.

Comment: @wayneh Did you import the header for your `GlobalData` type? Does the header define a class (i.e. marked with a `+`) method called `getInstance`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, and kind of. I made the mistake of forgetting that I changed "getInstance" to "getSingleton" so I could remember what was happening better - and of course, I promptly forgot. Nice catch - thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

when u need a variable / object that is accessible to all methods in an implementation data, u need to declare it on the header file, and then synthesize it on the implementation file (note that u may need to import the GlobalData header)

so

in header  (.h):

```
@class GlobalData;

@properties (nonatomic, strong) GlobalData *globDat;
```

and then at the implementation file (.m)

```
#import "blablabla.h"
#import "GlobalData.h"

@implementation blablabla

@synthesize globDat;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
globDat = [GlobalData getInstance];
}
```

good luck